# Fast algorithm to determine invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Imagine that there is an endomorphism $A \in \text{End(V)}$ and I want to find out the biggest non-trivial decomposition of the vector space into invariant subspaces. 
I am looking for the best way to do this:

My idea is to determine the minimal polynomial of the endomorphism try to decompose it into irreducible polynomials, plug the matrix A into each of this polynomials and determine the nullspace. In this case, every null space should be one invariant subspace. The question is, whether there is a faster way to do this?